# Prove the set of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0, 1]$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^{[0, 1]}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

My attempt(I don't know analysis, so I just looked up the properties of continuous functions):

Let $U$ be the set of continuous real valued functions. Let $u, v \in U$. Since the sum of continuous functions is continuous, $u + v$ is continuous. Since any polynomial is continuous, $a(u + v)$ is continuous. So, $a(u + v) \in U$. Since $0(u + v) = 0, 0 \in U$.

I am trying to learn how to do subspace proofs. Seeing a correct proof at least once would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: How can you assert that $a(u+v)$ is a polynomial?

Comment: Turns out I don't know what polynomials are either. How can I show $a(u + v) \in U$?

Comment: Forget about polynomials. If $a$ is a real and $v$ a continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$, then $av\colon t\mapsto av(t)$ is continuous too. The constantly-zero function $t\mapsto 0$ is continuous and is the $\bf 0$ of the vector space.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote; I think this seems like a perfectly reasonable question. I also don't understand the vote to close; the OP has indicated an attempt to solve the question (which is essentially correct).

Answer (score 2):

In order to verify that $U$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$, you need to check:

(1) if $u,u'\in U$ and $\alpha,\beta$ are scalars, then $\alpha u + \beta u'\in U$, and

(2) $0\in U$ (or, equivalently, that $U$ is nonempty, because together with (1), $0\in U$ is equivalent to $U\neq\emptyset$ (why?))

Thus, in this case, your proof is essentially correct - a linear combination of continuous real-valued functions is a continuous real-valued functions, and the zero function is a continuous real valued function. Note that there is nothing special about the domain $[0,1]$ here (except that it is a topological space, but don't worry about this if you don't know what that is). However, it is important that the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ is a field so it makes sense to add and scale continuous functions into $\mathbb{R}$, and thus have a vector space structure. For example, with the roles of $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ switched (i.e., functions from $\mathbb{R}$ into $[0,1]$), the problem wouldn't make sense because there would be no vector space structure.

Hope that helps!

Comment: (2) follows from (1) by taking $u'=u, \alpha = 1, \beta   = -1$.

Comment: Hi @copper.hat, thanks for your comment! You're right that, *assuming* $U\neq \emptyset$, (2) follows from (1) (there are a number of ways of proving this, e.g., what you suggest). However, it doesn't follow from (1) alone if $U=\emptyset$ ((1) is vacuously satisfied if $U=\emptyset$). I guess the entire point of (2) is to ensure that the empty set is not a subspace of any vector space.